# Selecting points not on end of line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, select-by-location

I have a data set of points from which I'm trying to make a selection of the points whose location is between two line segments. What would the way to do it?

Here's a picture to illustrate what I'm trying to get:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your Select By Location call, you can change the "Spatial Selection method" to *are within (Clementini) the source latyer feature*.  This will select the vertices and not endpoints.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @AlecZ. Although I found another solution, what you suggested also helps.